# Preventing Embedded Python from Running Shell Commands?

Tags: c++, python, shell

I want to embed Python 3.x in our C++ application to allow scripting of maintenance and other tasks.  It so far does everything we need including file manipulation.

The problem is that to meet some specifications (like PCI), we aren't allowed to arbitrarily run shell commands such as with subprocess.call or popen.

Is there a way to prevent and similar calls from working in embedded Python?

Comment: AFAIK, there are 3 ways to call external utilities ... `os.system`, `subprocess` and `commands`.  It seems like you could disable the second two simply by deleting the `subprocess.py` and `commands.py` from the library tree.  with `os`, you might be able to add `del system` in the os module... There might be other places/things you'd need to edit, but this is a start at least...

Comment: Some random thought, to add to the above, why not move the commands you dont want to use to another path or make the python run not as root but as restricted user with no access permission to the commands folder . If i remember right ,all commands are available in /bin /sin /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin/.

Comment: @Pradheep Commands can be anywhere.  You could set `PATH` to something non-existant, but the user can still invoke commands using an absolute path.  And there's no way you can say that a specific user doesn't have access to a folder.

Comment: It is a Windows app if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to remove all the modules that allow running arbitrary shell commands, i.e.: subprocess.py*, os.py*... and include only the modules that the end users are allowed to have immediate access to.

Comment: Thanks!  That pretty much works.  I need os, but another suggestion mentioned adding del system to the end of the bundled os.py.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application is really locked down I don't think you can prevent someone from loading their own python module from an arbitrary directory (with import) so I don't think you can prevent execution of arbitrary code as long as you have python embedded.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, I think that is an option we can lock down.  We don't arbitrarily load Python files, the python in inside another file.  So we can prevent the interpreter from working if there are any unknown .py files existing.  Also we lock down paths so import won't be able to find anything we don't want it to.  I'll have to remember to make sure this is complete.